# Paragraph Entity Query returns too many results

Tags: database, paragraphs

I'm trying to find a paragraph that have a certain taxonomy term value and on a matching parent node. I tried the code below, but it always returns over 30 values, when really only one paragraph entity is possible. Not sure what I'm missing.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('paragraph')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->condition('type', 'player_assignment')
    ->condition('field_year_season', $term_id)
    ->condition('parent_id', $node_id);

$results = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Have you looked with a database client to see what records are returned? I am going to wager a guess they are all 'status 1'.

Answer (score 1):

If this returns 30 paragraphs then all of them were at some point stored in the parent node, but not necessarily in the current revision. It might be easier to load the node and then check the paragraph field content of the current revision or, in case you don't know the node ID, start your entity query with the node entity:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->accessCheck(FALSE)
  ->condition('field_paragraph.entity.field_foo', 'bar');
```